# Синхронизация EJB с DB

Tags: java-ee, persistance, glassfish, jsp, ejb

Использую в проекте такую страшную штуку как EJB. Ближе к делу, есть функции, которые добавляют сразу много данных в базу данных и они сразу синхронизируются с EJB, а есть методы, которые добавляют один кортеж и синхронизации с EJBином не происходит. Прочитал в JEE6 Tutorial, что нужно использовать flush(), попробовал, но не помогло. Может кто-нибудь знает, как насильно запустить синхронизацию :-)

Пользуюсь NetBeans 6.9.1, все классы Entity, Session генерировал с помощью неё, в качестве AppServer'a GlassFish из коробки c NetBeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему добавив в методы фасада следующие 2 операции:

```
getEntityManager.flush();
getEntityManager.refresh(entity);
```

тем самым данные сразу добавляются в db и происходит синхронизация с ejb

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, для работы с базой данных вы используете технологию Java Persistence. В этом случае подобная ошибка может произойти в случае, если вы пишете в базу данных при помощи native query. Отключите кэш Persistence или используйте JPQL. Кроме того обратите внимание на то что корректно указываете ссылки при использовании связанных entity. Рассинхронизация происходит обычно из за того, что в базе данные изменились, а кэше JPA все еще нет.